# Why border is not around text?

Tags: html, css

I want the border to be around the text but it doesn't appear. What did I do wrong? Maybe I have to set position?

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #282A2E;
}

menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menu__item {
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <menu>
    <div class="menu__item">
      text
    </div>
  </menu>
</div>
```

Comment: You have given `#menu__item` instead of `.menu__item`

Comment: `#menu__item` refers to an ID but you have a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"">

<style>
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #282A2E;  }
menu {
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu_item {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width:fit-content;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <menu>
           <div class="menu_item">
               text
            </div>
        </menu>
    </div>
       
</body>
</html>
```

You were incorrectly defining the class `menu_item`. # indicates an **id**, not a class.

**Result:**

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"">

<style>
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #282A2E;  }
menu {
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu_item {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width:fit-content;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <menu>
           <div class="menu_item">
               text
            </div>
        </menu>
    </div>
       
</body>
</html>
```

I further added `width:fit-content;` to ensure that the border only surrounds the text, and not the entire width of the screen.

If you want it to look better, you could also add some padding like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"">

<style>
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #282A2E;  }
menu {
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu_item {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width:fit-content;
    padding:1em;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <menu>
           <div class="menu_item">
               text
            </div>
        </menu>
    </div>
       
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Using `border-color` is pretty unnecessary. You can just do it with `border: <width> <design> <color>`. For example, `border: 1px solid white`

Answer (score 1):

Using `#menu__item` means ID, not class. To edit css for the menu__item class, use:

```
.menu__item {
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you are using an ID (`#menu__item`) , but in HTML a class. Change one or the other to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to set the width of border.
- And you should change `#menu__item` to `.menu__item` because `menu__item` is class name.

```css
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #282A2E;  }
menu {
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu__item {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <menu>
    <div class="menu__item">
      text
    </div>
  </menu>
</div>
```